# How to replace drawable image with all screen size image using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

In my code I have many icons which are used in application. Now I want to change all icons with all its sizes like hdpi, xhdpi ect.

How to change all sizes of icons in a shortcut way? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library to make things easier for you to manipulate drawable in different screen sizes.
**Here is the** [Library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

You can put the height and width in SDP it will manage itself  for all screens

**For example like this**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_9sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_18sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

**OR**

Using this code you can get runtime Display's Width & Height

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

In a view you need to do something like this:

```
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager()
                         .getDefaultDisplay()
                         .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

You can get the screen sizes and manage itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your existing icon images to different dpi images you can use following approach.

Go to `File -> New -> Image Asset`. It will open a window shown below.

[image]

1. In **Icon Type** dropdown select `Action bar and tab icons`.
2. In **Asset Type** select `Image` radio button.
3. In Path provide path to your valid png image with transparent background.
4. Fill other options as it suits you.

After clicking Next it will show another preview window, Select Finish and your resources will be imported to different drawable folders.

Answer (score 1):

Use this online tool. You upload your icon in a good resolution and the tool exports all the necessary file sizes.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 1):

By the same icon name you have two options:

1. Vector drawable: If you have SVG image format then you can directly create vector drawable in your drawable folder that can help you with single file and multiple screen sizes icons.

OR

2. You can go through with icon generator tool, thereby drag and drop a single size image you can get same image with multiple sizes then just replace it by "show in explorer" option